# Adicionar data na tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, bootstrap-3

Eu to puxando uma API e colocando os dados dela dentro de uma tabela, mas esses dados vao para a parte table que é o td, mas quero colocar a data que os dados foram implementados lá, ai a data ficaria no th.

Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" width="100px" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr class="cliente">
                      <th class="cor">Quantidade</th>

                </tr>
                <tr class="clientess">
                      <th class="cor">Nº.Pedido</th>


                </tr>
                <tr class="fiscal">
                      <th class="cor">Nota Fiscal</th>

                </tr>
                <tr class="entprevista">
                      <th class="cor">Entrega Prevista</th>

                </tr>

                <tr class="data">
                  <th class="cor">Data</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PUXANDO API

```
    function load() {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("GET", "API AQUI");

  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var resposta = xhr.responseText;
      console.log("ola1");
      var clientes = JSON.parse(resposta);
      console.log("ola2");
      console.log(clientes);

      for (var i =0; i < 1; i++){
          console.log("ola3");
         var clientes_1 = clientes.TRACKER[i];
         adicionaClienteNaTabelaViagem(clientes_1);
         adicionaClienteNaTabelaViagemLogo(clientes_1);
         AdicionaNotaFiscal(clientes_1);
         AdicionaEntPrevista(clientes_1);
         AdicionaStatus(clientes_1);
     }

  });

  xhr.send();
      }
      window.onload = load;
```

ALGUNS DADOS QUE COLOCO NA TD DA TABELA

```
function AdicionaNotaFiscal(fiscal) {

    var notaTr = fiscalTr(fiscal);
    var tabelas = document.querySelector(".fiscal");


    tabelas.appendChild(notaTr);

}

function fiscalTr(fiscal) {
    var notaTr = document.createElement("tr");
    notaTr.classList.add("fiscal");

      notaTr.appendChild(notaTd(fiscal.NFISCA, "info-nota-fiscal"));

    return notaTr;
}

function notaTd(dado, classe) {

    var teste = document.querySelector(".fiscal");

    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.classList.add(classe);
    td.textContent = dado;

    return td;
}
```

Aí nesse th que ta escrito "quantidade", "nota fiscal"... eu queria que ficasse a data do dia que eu postei o api

Comment: já tentou com o input? `Input type = DateTime-Local`

Comment: Nao. Isso seria dentro do th?

Comment: a desculpa li sua pergunta errada, você quer que o sistema rode automatico né? achei que era pro usuario selecionar a data e hora

Comment: vai ter que ser um `.js` pra fazer essa rotina

Comment: Exatamente. Aí nao estou conseguindo fazer isso

Comment: olha esse exemplo aqui veja se você consegue inserir ele no seu código (https://temptable.com.br/2015/11/exibir-data-e-hora-atual-em-html.html)

Comment: Já tentei esse, não é desse jeito que quero

Comment: achei um código bem simples aqui e bem eficiente `var teste = new Date()
document.write(teste.toLocaleString());`

Comment: Verdade. O único problema é como vou colocar isso ta table do HTML lá

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já consegui resolver o problema. Um colega do site ajudou:

```
function addColunaData(data){
  var tabela   = document.getElementsByClassName("table")[0];
  //Pego a primeira coluna da primeira linha da tabela de classe table.
  var primeiraColuna = tabela.rows[0].cells[0];

  //concateno a data ao valor da primeira coluna.
  primeiraColuna.append(' ' + data);

}


//Abaixo sua forma de criar a data
var data = new Date();
var dia  = data.getDate();
var mes  = data.getMonth();
var ano  = data.getFullYear();
var hora = data.getHours();
var min  = data.getMinutes();
var seg  = data.getSeconds();
var str_data = dia + '/' + (mes+1) + '/' + ano;
var str_hora = hora + ':' + min;

//Concateno as variaves em uma única para realizar a atribuição
var data = str_data + ' ' + str_hora;

//Chamo a função para adicionar a data criada acima na coluna.
addColunaData(data);
```